# i need help for php regex

Tags: php

hello allll thats me code which valid you enter only english letter 
preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z]$#i', $text)

how i can write " or ' between [] thats meaning i need to make regex empowering user enter " or '

Comment: Please God please put more effort into this. You're asking experts for free consultations. At least write full sentences, and when someone gives you the answer, mark it as accepted.

Comment: I would suggest you accept answers by clicking the check mark next to the answer that helps you. So far, you have only accepted 7% of the questions you have asked. This does not give others a very big incentive to help you.

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match('#^[\'"a-z]+$#i', $text)
```

This will match a string with any a-z A-Z ' ". But no spaces.